# How to Update the table column with different values using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Following is my table

```
EmpID    Ename    Gender
1         John     Male
2         Mike     Female
3         Dwane    Female
4         Clark    Male
```

Now, I want to update the table by setting EmpID as 22 and 56 (will get these values from nested query) where Gender is Male. Likewise, I've 100 of rows in my table and I need to update EmpID values as per the inner query for all the Male values.

I know that the following query is wrong. Let's say we have 4 rows with Gender as Male and so, I want to update EmpID with new values that I'll be getting nested query.

```
Update tableName set EmpID = (23,54,65,67) where Gender='Male'.
```

What will be the SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: What's the criteria to assign from the nested query? By the order you get the `tableName` rows? You probably need dynamic SQL to build the query as you run across the results of the "subquery" and get the next row of the result (e.g. from a cursor)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using case when

```
 Update tableName 
 set EmpID=case EmpID when 1 then 23 when 2 then 54 when 3 then 65 else 67
    end 
where Gender='Male'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update TableName set Ename="new value", Gender="new value" where EmpId=1
```

This will allow you to update a specific Employee based on there ID.